# Symfony 1.0 - Extend sfRouting

Tags: php, routes, symfony1

Anyone know if the following 'class' entry in routing.yml is possible in SF1.0? I tried to add it and override some methods like `getInstance()` and `getCurrentRouteName()`, but they never get called upon, even though I am making calls to them manually.

```
checkout_landing:
  class: CustomRoute # Can I do this in SF1.0?
  url: /checkout/landing/:k/*
  param: { module: sharedCheckout, action: landing }
```

We have implemented this 'per-route' custom class configuration in SF1.2, but it doesn't seem to be working for SF1.0. I suspect for SF1.0 I will have to add a custom class entry to the factories.yml file which will affect all routes.

Bonus question: Anyone able to emulate the 'extra_parameters_as_query_string' in SF1.0? Right now, with the above url entry, and GET params are converted to pseduo sub-dirs, for example a querystring like:

```
$params = array('foo' => 'bar', 'pet' => 'dog');

$url = sprintf('@checkout_landing?%s', http_build_query($params));

// Looks like:

http://example.com/checkout/landing/foo/bar/cat/dog

// I need it to look like

http://example.com/checkout/landing?foo=bar&pet=dog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed the compiled cached code for routes, and sure enough in SF1.0 there are no custom object references based on 'Class' entries in the yaml file. However when I view compiled cache code for routes generated in SF1.4, the custom objects are available.

As upgrading is not an option, I opted to generate the urls the old fashioned way, manually.

Comment: As an aside, can you elaborate on why upgrading is not an option? AFAIK all you need to do is change the content of ````lib/symfony```` - even if you're stuck with the PEAR install, you can always change the ````sf_lib_dir```` param to ignore it. Not trying to troll, genuinely curious.

Comment: I help support a large codebase which is constantly under heavy traffic loads. It would be a large project to port the functionality from SF1.0 to SF1.4, for example moving forms to form classes etc. The biz side can't justify the cost of dev time and risk breakage. We port when we can, but we will probably be supporting the 1.0 api for at least another 18-24 months :(

Comment: That's the problem then, you didn't read my answer properly - don't upgrade to 1.4, upgrade to 1.3 - with the sfCompatPlugin this is guaranteed to be backwards compatible, and you then can extend into sf1.2+ code territory without too much fear. sf1.3 is essentially sf1.0 with some extras.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, neither of those things is possible in sf1.0 without either making the compromise you suggest for a custom extension of sfRouting (in `factories.yml`), or adding the functionality of sf1.2+ for the `extra_parameters_as_query_string`.

I would suggest the easiest option for you is to upgrade to the last stable version of sf1.3 ([sf1.3.11](http://symfony.com/download#symfony1)) and using the bundled `sf10CompatPlugin` to help you emulate the sf1.0 features you use in the existing app, while adding the sf1.2+ features you desire from the sf1.3 core.

There are very few compatibility errors from doing this, and I have used it myself on dozens of projects without any hitches.

Comment: For my personal projects I use SF1.4 which avoids the issue altogether, but for work we cannot upgrade from SF1.0. Just looking to see if someone had a work around.